# How to create a custom textbox with set text, font type, font size, font colour in Powerpoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I need to create a custom textbox in the active slide with set text, font type, font size, font colour, and bold and italics feature in Powerpoint 2007 using a macro.

I am currently using this code:

```
Sub InsertTextBox()
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set newTextBox = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    100, Top:=100, Width:=541.44, Height:=43.218)
    With newTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Slide Title"
        .Font.Size = 24
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Colour = RGB(107, 107, 107)  
End With
End Sub
```

Its throwing an exception in .Font.Colour saying that this property is not associated with the object. Also i need to incorporate a feature for bold and italics..Plz help me on this

Comment: `.Font.Color =` is correct property. For bold use this one `.Font.Bold = true` and for italic quite similar: `.Font.Italic = true`.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(107, 107, 107)
```

And as Kazjaw points out, it's .Color rather than .Colour

Comment: Hi Steve...In the above code if I want to make just the text "Slide Title" in bold and insert it a s a text box, while the remaining text after Slide Title should be not in bold..how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find on a range to locate a string within a textrange and return a new textrange consisting of just the found text:

```
With newTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange
    With .Find("Slide Title")
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End With
```

In practice, you'd want to use Instr to verify that the text you're looking for is indeed in the text box.